# A dynamic SAS program to consolidate dates of events that are nested within each other

Tags: sas

[image: Example]
Hello,

I want to write a dynamic program which helps me to flag the start and end dates of events that are nested within the consolidated dates that are present at the top of each Pt.ID in the attached example. I can easily do these if there is only one such consolidated period per Pt.ID. However, there could be more than one such consolidated periods per Pt. ID. (As shown for second Pt.ID, 1002). As shown in the example, the events that fall within the consolidated period/s are fagged as "Y" in the flag variable and if they don't fall within the consolidated period then they are flagged as "N" in this variable. How can I write a program that accounts for all of such consolidated periods per Pt.ID and then compare them with the dates for the rest of the events of a particular patient and flag events which fall within any of those consolidated periods?

Thank you.

Comment: What did you try? Can you post the data as data and not a photograph?  Can you post the desired result?

Comment: `retain` & an `array` in data step should do what you need even if the rules are somewhat complex. If the flag value doesn't depend on multiple lines of "consolidate dates", you can also simply join data where `event_ID = .` and `event_ID ne .` to find which rows have `Flag = 'Y'` and then join the `Flag` info back to original dataset.

Comment: How can I add the dataset program without exceeding the characters limit here?  I was unable to do it due to this limit. @Tom

Comment: data Sample;
 infile datalines missover;
 input Pt_ID  Event_ID Category $ Start_Date : mmddyy10. Start_Day End_date : mmddyy10. End_day Duration ;
 format Start_date End_date mmddyy10.;
 datalines;
 1001 . Moderate 8/5/2016 256  9/3/2016 285 30
 1001 1 Moderate 3/8/2016 106  3/16/2016 114 9
 1001 2 Moderate 8/5/2016 256  8/14/2016 265 10
 1001 3 Moderate 8/21/2016 272  8/24/2016 275 4
 1001 4 Moderate 8/23/2016 274  9/3/2016 285 12
 
 --Continuation of this code is in next post. @Tom

Comment: 1002 . Severe  11/28/2016 13  12/19/2016 34 22
 1002 . Severe  2/6/2017 83  2/28/2017 105 23
 1002 1 Severe  11/28/2016 13  12/5/2016 20 8
 1002 2 Severe  12/12/2016 27  12/19/2016 34 8
 1002 3 Severe  1/9/2017 55  1/12/2017 58 4
 1002 4 Severe  2/6/2017 83  2/13/2017 90 8
 1002 5 Severe  2/20/2017 97  2/28/2017 105 9
 1002 6 Severe  3/17/2017 122  3/24/2017 129 8
 1002 7 Severe  5/4/2017 170  5/13/2017 179 10
 1002 8 Severe  5/24/2017 190  5/30/2017 196 7
 1002 9 Severe  6/9/2017 206  6/13/2017 210 5
 ;
run;    @Tom

Comment: Are you saying that the records with missing EVENTID represent the periods that you want to compare the events to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So join the event records with the period records and calculate whether the event is within the period.  Then you could take the MAX over all periods.
For example here is code for your sample that creates a binary 1/0 flag variable called INCLUDED.

```
data Sample;
  infile datalines missover;
  input Pt_ID Event_ID Category $ Start_Date : mmddyy10. 
        Start_Day End_date : mmddyy10. End_day Duration 
  ; 
  format Start_date End_date mmddyy10.; 
datalines; 
1001  .  Moderate 8/5/2016  256  9/3/2016  285  30 
1001  1  Moderate 3/8/2016  106  3/16/2016  114  9 
1001  2  Moderate 8/5/2016  256  8/14/2016  265  10 
1001  3  Moderate 8/21/2016  272  8/24/2016  275  4 
1001  4  Moderate 8/23/2016  274  9/3/2016  285  12 
1002  .  Severe   11/28/2016  13  12/19/2016  34  22 
1002  .  Severe   2/6/2017  83  2/28/2017  105  23 
1002  1  Severe   11/28/2016  13  12/5/2016  20  8 
1002  2  Severe   12/12/2016  27  12/19/2016  34  8 
1002  3  Severe   1/9/2017  55 1/12/2017  58  4 
1002  4  Severe   2/6/2017  83  2/13/2017  90  8 
1002  5  Severe   2/20/2017  97  2/28/2017  105  9 
1002  6  Severe   3/17/2017  122  3/24/2017  129  8 
1002  7  Severe   5/4/2017  170  5/13/2017  179  10 
1002  8  Severe   5/24/2017  190  5/30/2017  196  7 
1002  9  Severe   6/9/2017  206  6/13/2017  210  5 
; 

proc sql ;
  create table want as
  select a.*
       , max(b.start_date <= a.start_date and b.end_date >= a.end_date ) as Included
  from sample a
  left join sample b
  on a.pt_id = b.pt_id and missing(b.event_id)
  group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
  order by a.pt_id, a.event_id, a.start_date , a.end_date
  ;
quit;
```

Comment: Thank you @ Tom. This is exactly what I needed. How did you write this long post as one comment?

Comment: Comments are short. Questions and Answers can be much longer.

Comment: Hi @Tom, I just have one question regarding this. How is the max function in this case evaluating to 1 or 0. I have searched everywhere to see how the data works in the PDV in this case but haven't found anything. Will you please explain how data is handled in PDV in this case?

Comment: The MAX() function is the SQL aggregation function. It will find the maximum value over the group.  What it is taking the max of is the result of evaluating the boolean expression.  SAS will evaluate boolean expressions to either 1 (true) or 0 (false).  So max(condition) is calculating if condition is ever true. Min(condition) would calculate if the condition is never false, in which case the min() will be one..